# Award user points for selecting an avatar?

Tags: userpoints, media

I'd like to award my happy little users when they select an avatar.

Anyone know of a module that melds [User Points](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints) and [Avatar Selection](http://drupal.org/project/avatar_selection)?

Both modules are awesome, but I can't find a way to combine them into thanks-for-making-your-profile-pretty goodness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there already exists a module for this.

What you need to do is implement [hook_user_update()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.api.php/function/hook_user_update/7) and check if the user now has a picture assigned but didn't before. If so, use [userpoints_userpointsapi()](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/userpoints/userpoints-7.x-1.x--userpoints.module/function/userpoints_userpointsapi/7-1) to grant the user the number of points you want.

Something like this:

```
<?php
function yourmodule_user_update(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  if (!empty($edit['picture'] && empty($account->picture)) {
    $params = array(
      'uid' => $account->uid,
      'points' => 10,
      // You probably want to provide additional arguments, 
      // refer to the API documentation.
    );
    userpoints_userpointsapi($params);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Actually, there exists a module already for this, see http://drupal.org/project/userpoints_user_picture.